# I am receiving 2 line items when running workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I am very new to creating workflows; this is my very first one.

After creating a new item, I would like my workflow to push the result for a calculated column.  And it does that, but also adds another line item.

```
This is my workflow:
1. Create Item in Project / ACR Number Assignment Log.
2. '{WorkflowVariable:Change Control}' equals '{WorkflowVariable:Change    Control}' or '{WorkflowVariable:Project File}' equals '{WorkflowVariable:Project File}'.
3. The Location field on the current item equals 'VH' or The Location field on the current item equals 'MN' or The Location field on the current item equals 'DR'.
4. Commit pending changes.
5. Wait for a change in 'ID'.
6. Send a message to:
{ItemProperty:Created By}

7. End the workflow.
```

This is my result:
CC-IS-VH-000
CC-IS-VH-059

Of course, the second line item is the desired result.  How can I achieve only the desired result?